# How to install LP_solve solver on Yosemite?

Tags: macos, java

I want to install java based "lp_solve" [LP solver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/files/lpsolve/5.5.2.0/) on my MacBook Air, OS X Yosemite. I tried to follow the instructions given [here](https://diegoresearch.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/using-lp_solve-in-java-with-mac-os-x/). But when I run sh ccc.osx, it is not creating the liblpsolve55.dylib and liblpsolve55.dylib. I need help installing this solver. Or maybe suggest me a similar solver which is easy to install on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I will take care of the links from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is doing it using [homebrew](http://brew.sh). You just need to type the following couple of commands in a terminal window:

```
brew tap brewsci/science
brew install lp_solve
```

If you don't have homebrew installed, just type the following to install before the previous commands:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this thing successfully installed the LP solver. I will use the LP solver and confirm whether it works fine or not.

Comment: Do you know how to get this lp_solve working in Python or R? I got some lpsolve already working for R but not for Python.

Comment: `homebrew/science` is deprecated and `brewsci/science` should be used instead.

Comment: Could also use: `brew install brewsci/science/lp_solve`

Answer (score 1):

What's your problem in specific? Any error messages?

I just tried to compile it and I didn't run into any problem:

```
$ cd lpsolve55/
$ sh ccc.osx
$ ls  bin/osx64/
liblpsolve55.a     liblpsolve55.dylib
```

Comment: I tried to do exactly this, but I cannot see the liblpsolve55.a & liblpsolve55.dylib files.